# Adding custom validation to core fields

Tags: plugin-development, validation

I've been looking at http://straightupcraft.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft which seems to concentrate on custom models. However I am looking to validate data posted to a plugin that stores that data as core EntryModels.

So let's say you create a Section and assign some Fields in its field layout. You can set each Field to be required but I want to do more than that and check if it's an integer or if it's unique.

I am currently doing that in my service class:

```
private function validateReference()
{
    $reference = craft()->request->getPost('reference');

    $existingEntryCount = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)->total(array(
        'reference' => $reference
    ));

    return ($existingEntryCount === 0);
}
```

That all works but I am wondering if instead I should be setting the validation properties of each Field in this service and then just running a core validate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to write your own [field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types) for this. You can extend one of the built-in field types if you want.

You would put your custom validation logic in your field type’s [validate()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#validate-detail) method.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. We're using text, textarea and select fields, so we'd have to create 3 custom field types just to add some basic validation in. Is there no simpler way other than validating directly in the service?

Comment: I ended up creating a simple text field that validates uniqueness across the relevant ElementType: https://github.com/fuel-digital/Craft-Unique-Text-FieldType